# Enabling logback logging with Spring boot app for Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, logback, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to enable logback logging for spring boot app on Google app engine.
I followed [these](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) instructions.

But stuck with below exception. I referred https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880 , https://github.com/latacora/unsiemly/issues/9 and https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2380 but nothing worked. Any idea what could be missing?

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.batching.Semaphore64.notNegative(Semaphore64.java:86)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.batching.Semaphore64.<init>(Semaphore64.java:46)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.batching.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:146)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.BatchingCallSettings.<init>(BatchingCallSettings.java:70)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.BatchingCallSettings.<init>(BatchingCallSettings.java:46)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.BatchingCallSettings$Builder.build(BatchingCallSettings.java:146)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.LoggingSettings.<init>(LoggingSettings.java:245)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.LoggingSettings.<init>(LoggingSettings.java:104)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.LoggingSettings$Builder.build(LoggingSettings.java:703)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:114)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:64)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:58)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:472)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:134)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:108)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:41)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.getLogging(LoggingAppender.java:201)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.start(LoggingAppender.java:166)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:17
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:145)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:81)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:59)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicat
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:21
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMultic
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticas
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticas
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticas
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletI
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.jav
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-02-08 12:52:29.359:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@2b7962a2{HTTP/
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:274)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:368)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
[INFO] GCLOUD:
```

My dependency tree with excluding conflicting guava dependencies.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Okr 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ okr ---
[INFO] com.arrkgroup.okr:okr:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.webjars:webjars-locator:jar:0.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:4.0.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:jar:9.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:jar:9.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.58:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.9.59:test
[INFO] +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.jhipster:jhipster:jar:1.1.8:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.papertrail:profiler:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.bundles:json:jar:20090211_1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:test
[INFO] +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-heroku-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-localconfig-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-data:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:jar:1.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:jar:1.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:1.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-google:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:jar:1.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.azure:spring-social-microsoft-graph:jar:0.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:1.4.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.3.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.3.8.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:1.4.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:jar:1.4.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jdo:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.transaction:transaction-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud.sql:postgres-socket-factory:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-core:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-sqladmin:jar:v1beta4-rev25-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.44:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging-logback:jar:0.32.0-alpha:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO]       +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.6.Final:compile
[INFO]       +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:0.1.26:compile
[INFO]       +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]       |  \- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]       +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]       +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-logging-v2:jar:0.1.26:compile
[INFO]       +- io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.7.0:compile (version selected from constraint [1.7.0,1.7.0])
[INFO]       |  |  +- com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile (version selected from constraint [4.1.16.Final,4.1.16.Final])
[INFO]       |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |  |     \- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |  |        \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |  \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       |     \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO]       +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]       \- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.349 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-16T13:03:17+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: seems like you're using a non compatible version of google guava

Comment: I excluded all the other guava versions in pom and kept the one which is with google-cloud-logging-logback. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: you're saying that the missing method isn't actually missing? prove it

Comment: I haven't said missing method isn't missing. I tried to eliminate other guava library from dependencies and kept only the one logback is using.

Comment: if the error persists, then this seems to be the wrong version

Comment: Could you post the pom.xml config file?